# I got a job in Saudi Arabia. What are my tax liabilities in India

Tags: taxes, india, income, dtaa, saudi-arabia

I just received an offer from Saudi Arabia but I will be required to be in Saudi for only 4 month in the whole year. So what is the tax implications on the earning that I have in Saudi.

What are the tax brackets for such income. If some one can help me with a breakup of the tax for 48K USD. Need answers asap please as I will have to accept it basis some clarity I get.

Answer (score 1):

If you are outside of India for less than 182 days in a financial year [1st April to 31st March]; you will be treated as resident Indian for tax purposes in India. If you are Non Resident Indian, then from tax point of view you have zero tax liability in India.

If you are spending less than 182 days, then provisions of DTAA come in place. As per the [DTAA, there is no tax in India](https://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/dtaa/comprehensive%20agreements/108690000000000075.htm) for the salary in Saudi. Please take a professional advise as DTAA are complex and need complete understanding of taxation between 2 countries.